# htaccess rewrite url contains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block some urls in my site, for example i want to "ban" urls and give them 403 when contains words like options, k2 or component. The problem is that htaccess not work properly

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(option|k2|component) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Is blocking when bot attack www.example.com/option=?asdasdad
but its not blocking when bot is attacking www.example.com/index.php/option=?asdad

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the above and Put only  the following code :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule (option|k2|component) - [F]
```

Comment: its not working:
`www.mydomain.com:80 155.254.203.181 - - [09/May/2016:16:22:59 +0200] "GET /?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=378647 HTTP/1.0" 200 12004 "-" "PHP/5.2.82"`